# Utility of the [grammaire] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that most, if not all, questions with the tag [grammaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaire) can be complemented with a tag detailing which part of the grammar the question is about - for example, [conjugaison](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjugaison), [pluriel](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pluriel), [prepositions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions)...

Which makes me wonder: do we actually want that tag at all?

Note I'm not really used yet to what a good tag system is or not, so please consider this question more as me wanting to know whether it's better to have it or not, and why; rather than me asking for deleting it altogether.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that "Conjugaison" is absolutely grammar. On the contrary maybe we can have "orthographe" question on "pluriel", "préposition" and other.

So maybe this tag can be useful to refine the content of those questions anyway.

Answer (score 4):

About *conjugaison*, *plural* and *prepositions* examples, I think questions tagged with these might independently be about:

- *orthographe* (how to write some word/verb, which preposition follows some other word…). Even though for most words/verbs/expressions the *orthographe* can be found easily on the net, maybe some particular cases could be accepted here.
- *grammaire* (how to group words together, *accords*, would a plural be accepted here… independently of the semantics).
- *sémantique*, and there's already a tag [sens](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sens). (e.g. what is the meaning of this plural/tense in this sentence…)

Even others:

- comparison with other languages
- origin of some specific unusual usage

So, in my opinion, *grammaire* must be kept as a tag. For example, I've got *grammaire* as a favorite tag, and that's the only way to select only questions related to grammar.